# My .htaccess does not work ModRewrite already enabled

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here is my .htacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^home(|/)$ index.php?p=home

RewriteRule ^community(|/)$ index.php?p=community

RewriteRule ^categories(|/)$ index.php?p=categories

</IfModule>

Options -Indexes   
IndexIgnore *
```

what im making wrong ?

Website: bitprime.us

i already enabled mod rewrite on my server:
root@flarenetwork:/var/www/bitprime.us/www# a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled

Comment: Place a definite syntax error in the `.htaccess` file, monitor the http servers error log file and make a request. You should get an error, if not then the file is not considered at all. If so, then you may have forgotten to use the `AllowOverride` directive.

Comment: Apart from that it certainly might be that the file _is_ considered, but your rule set simply has no effect on the requests. FOr us to be able to help in that case you will have to add details to the question.